# LIN BUS - why 50 mΩ in series?

Tags: automotive, lin

I can see there is 50 mΩ in LIN bus with LIN ICs.
But I don't understand why it is there.

Does anyone have an idea why I see 50 mΩ in the bus line?

Comment: How about a circuit or relevant data sheet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is almost certainly used as a current sensing resistor for LIN's [Bus Shunt Method](https://lin-cia.org/fileadmin/microsites/lin-cia.org/resources/documents/Bus_Shunt_Revision_1.pdf) (BSM) of node position detection (NPD), also known as autoaddressing. This method allows a device to detect if it is the last device on the bus, even if it doesn't have an address assigned to it already.

Comment: Thank, it is definitely for Bus Shunt Method (BSM) even if I cannot check all circuits. I can simply check why there is a shunt from this link as well.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Interconnect_Network